# Drupal url encoding

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, urlencode

I am having trouble properly encoding URL data. Using the following code:

```
$redirect = drupal_urlencode("user/register?destination=/node/1");
drupal_goto( $redirect );
```

but, the URL that comes up in my browser test is the following:

```
http://testsite.com/user/register%253Fdestination%253D/node/1
```

I thought using the `drupal_urlencode` function should fix this encoding issue. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better off using the built in [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/6) function to create your URL, if you pass an array as the `query` parameter it handles URL encoding for you:

```
$options = array(
  'absolute' => TRUE,
  'query' => array('destination' => '/node/1')
);
$redirect = url('user/register', $options);

drupal_goto( $redirect );
```

`drupal_encode()` will encode the whole string that you pass to it, so if you want to do it your original way it would look like this:

```
$redirect = 'user/register?' . drupal_urlencode("destination=/node/1");
drupal_goto( $redirect );
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct, as [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6) uses the `url()` function itself on the passed in parameters. The right way would be to pass the query parameter array as the second parameter to `drupal_goto()`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of doing this in Drupal 6 is:

```
drupal_goto("user/register","destination=/node/1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code from Clive worked for me..

```
    $options = array(
  'absolute' => TRUE,
  'query' => array('destination' => '/node/1')
);
$redirect = url('user/register', $options);

drupal_goto( $redirect );
```